# How to solve build error for product flavor, when a referenced but unnecessary source/resource not found?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project and it has 2 product flavors with their own directories:

build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    productFlavors {
            free {
                applicationId "com.sample.free"
                 buildConfigField "boolean", "free", "true"
            }
            paid {
                applicationId "com.sample"
                buildConfigField "boolean", "free", "false"
            }
    }
}
```

And I have a class (such as `PaidOperationClass`) which is only used at `paid` flavor. So, I put that class under `src/paid/java` directory. And I have another  class(such as `CommonClass`) which is used by both flavors. So I put that under `src/main/java` directory:

```
src/main/  --> has CommonClass
src/free/
src/paid/  --> has PaidOperationClass
```

In `CommonClass` I have a method such as:

```
if(!BuildConfig.FREE) {
    PaidOperationClass.doSomeStuff();
}
```

So the `PaidOperationClass` is referenced(has an import) but never used by free build.

If I build the application for `paid` flavor everything works perfect. But if I try to build it for `free` flavor, it fails because referenced but unnecessary class is not found. **How do you solve this without code (class/method) replication (such as putting a dummy `PaidOperationClass` under `free` flavor)?** Are there any gradle options which ignores this kind of build errors while building?

**Edit:**  I need a gradle solution which won't need code replication. An annotation based custom script maybe, which removes unnecessary code for product flavors at compile time.

Comment: No, you have to fix it in your code.

Comment: @MimmoGrottoli yes but there must be an easy way with gradle.

Comment: No, there isn't. Gradle is the build system not the app code.

Comment: @DevrimTuncer Do you have found a solution?

Comment: @CeccoCQ no, not yet. But I'm working on the annotation idea.

Comment: @DevrimTuncer I've the same needs. If you want an help, you can contact me.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, because the import statement is inside the `CommonClass` and it is not able to resolve `PaidOperationClass` in the free flavor.

One way to achieve it is:

Create an empty class in **Free flavor**:

```
public class PaidOperationClass{

  public static void doSomeStuff(){
      //do nothing..    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution might be to create a class: IPaidOperations that is housed in the /src/main directory that the PaidOperationClass implements. Then just use the interface in the CommonClass.

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the `paid` package from the `free` package whether or not your use:

```
if(!BuildConfig.FREE) {
     PaidOperationClass.doSomeStuff();
}
```

So I suggest one of two options:

**1.**
So if you have a piece of code that is never used, why do you keep it there? Remove it and replace it with:

```
if(!BuildConfig.FREE) {
     // Do something within the imported packages.
}
```

Otherwise, you must import the `paid` package.

**2.**
Or have two `free` package versions

`free_paid` and `free_no_paid` and remove the reference to `paid` in the `free_no_paid` and use this when compiling without `paid` and use the `free_paid` package when compiling with `paid`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create two `CommonClass`es - both in `free` and `paid` source set (but not in `main`) which contain code specific to particular flavor. For example:
`src/free/java/.../CommonClass.java`:

```
doSomeStuff() {
  doSomeFreeStuff();    
}
```

`src/paid/java/.../CommonClass.java`:

```
doSomeStuff() {
  doSomePaidStuff();    
}
```

In such case code located in `main` source set can reference `CommonClass#doSomeStuff()` no matter which flavor is built. Only one `CommonClass` for particular flavor will be compiled. In other words instead of using ifs manually you let gradle to choose appropriate class to compile.

You can also extract really common code (which is not dependent on anything specific to `free` nor `paid`) from `CommonClass` to abstract class ie. `BaseCommonClass` placed in `main` source set and let `CommonClass` extend it.